# If function doesn't return false?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following `click` event:

```
$('#planung').click(function(){
    if($current != $('#planungtext')){
        console.log($current);
        console.log($('#planungtext'));
        $($current).removeClass('active');
        setTimeout(function(){$('#planungtext').addClass('active')}, 1000);
        $current = $('#planungtext');
    }
});
```

I used the log to see the contents of my variable and the `'#planungtext'` element. They are exactly the same, but the if function doesn't work as desired, as it is still going into it.

$current is not set before the first time the element is clicked.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Although there are many workarounds, the correct way to compare jQuery objects *in jQuery* is with `is`: http://api.jquery.com/is/ Answer added below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two jQuery objects point at the same DOM elements, but are different arrays (jQuery objects are essentially just arrays behind the scenes *with extra stuff*).

Use jQuery `is` http://api.jquery.com/is/ to test if the same selector would match them:

```
if(!$current.is('#planungtext')){
```

The fastest way to do that check "manually" is:

```
if ($current[0].id !== '#planungtext'){
```

It is mentioned in comment that $current is a jQuery variable (good naming standard) but initially `undefined` in which case almost every solution posted will crash. You need to initialise $current to an empty jQuery object to give the most consistent behavior (jQuery objects should never be undefined to be used like that, else you need to re-wrap it. e.g. with `$($current)` which I do not recommend as a solution to an uninitialised jQuery variable):

```
var $current = $();   // $() returns an empty jQuery object
```

Comment: Hey, this won't work because my $current, is defined after the first time something is clicked. So like this the console fires "cannot read property is of undefined" or sth.

Comment: Initiallise $current to `$()` which is an empty jQuery object.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `$current` is another jQuery object, you can't compare objects like that. You can however compare their inner values. Change:

```
$current != $('#planungtext')
```

To:

```
$current[0] != $('#planungtext')[0]
```

Comment: You might explain "why" you can't compare two jQuery objects like that so folks understand why your solution is required and why you can compare two DOM elements.

Comment: OP left out the small detail that `$current` is both a jQuery variable and not initialised, so will crash on `[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

If your comparing 2 html input element, you might want to check only the **id** attribute.

Since **#planungtext** is already a unique identifier.

```
$($current).attr('id') !== 'planungtext'
```

Comment: The `id` attribute would never have a leading '#' character. OP must have changed it to work.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry. Forgot to say this. The # is wrong of course. Please edit your answer

Comment: There is also a redundant `$()` around `$current` (variable prefixed with $ are typically jQuery objects.

Comment: Also it should have been `!==` for the example shown. :)

Comment: When i leave away the $(), it says "cannot read property of undefined". With $() it works

Comment: @Frederik Witte: That is because $current is not initialised to $() (empty jQuery object). The extra `$()` is just avoiding a crash on an undefined object and should not have been needed.